# butterknife is not working when in signed apk

Tags: android, apk, butterknife

I created an app using butterknife to implement onclick, ontouch,etc function, it works fine when I test it on my android devices, and it also works good when I install the debug-apk in the android deivces. However, when I generated an signed apk and try to run it in my android device, the "onclick" and "ontouch" are not working.I generated the apk using Android studio. Anyone knows the reason why this happens?

Comment: have you enabled proguard?

Answer (score 3):

Copied from http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/
Use these rules in proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that's the reason, do I only need to copy paste these rules to the proguard-rules.pro file?

Answer (score 0):

Add
**-keepnames class * { @butterknife.Bind *;}**
to the proguard file